# python list comprehension unzipping multiple returns

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension, unzip

anyone have any idea how to unpack the values in a tuple for a list comprehension?

So a practical example:

```
def func(x,y):
    return x*2, y*2

x = [1, 2, 3]; y = [1, 2, 3]

a, b = [ func(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y) ]
```

Unfortunately, that gives me an error sayin' there are too many values to unpack...

I've tried

```
zip(*func(i,j)) 
(a,b) = ...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you mean the following?:

```
a, b = zip(*[func(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y)])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for x1,y1 in [func(i,j) for i, j in zip(x,y)]:
     # do something with x1,y1
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the list comprehension returns something like

```
[(1,1), (4,4), (6,6),..]
```

so the list contains more than just two elements.

I don't see why you can't just do:

```
a = [i*2 for i in x]
b = [i*2 for i in y]
```

If you are worried about duplicate code, create a function:

```
def func(l):
    return [i*2 for i in l]

a, b = func(x), func(y)
```

Trying to pack everything in one line, using fancy list unpacking etc.,  does not necessarily increase readability.

Comment: Sometimes; you write something definite and you never want to write it again, this is one of those things. Like a regex expression, just crank it out hard one night and get it over with.